# Text based game input

Tags: python, user-input

I might just be being stupid, but I really cant figure this out. I'm making a text based game and in order to simulate character movement in different scenarios, I have used the following code:

```
 import random

 north = ("There is a path to the North. ")
 south = ("There is a path to the South. ") 
 east  = ("There is a path to the East. ")
 west = ("There is a path to the West. ")

 nsew = [north, south, east, west]

 print ("You find yourself in a woodland clearing. ")

 print (random.choice(nsew))
 print (random.choice(nsew))
 print (random.choice(nsew))
 print (random.choice(nsew))

 direction = input("Which way do you go? ")
```

This should print four random items from the list, which it does. I want to be able to do something like:

```
if direction == ("North"):
    print ("You decide to go North.")
```

but with an if statement for each one, so that if the user types "east" the program will respond with "you decide to go East"

Thanks

Comment: What is the programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

paths = []
tiaptt = "There is a path to the "
nsew = ["north", "south", "east", "west"]
amount = random.randrange(1,4)


for path in random.sample(nsew,amount):
    print tiaptt+path
    paths.append(path.lower())

direction = raw_input("Which way do you go? ")

try:
    index = paths.index(direction.lower())
    print "You have chosen to go %s"%paths[index]
except:
    print "You have chosen a wrong direction"
```

hope this helps. It works in python 2.7, if you use 3+ you might want to change my raw_input to input. and put () around the prints.

```
print ("You have chosen to go %s"%paths[index])
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you first read the user input, set all the letters to lowercase and then compare the resulted string with 'north', 'south', 'east' and 'west'.